# Microsoft Outlook Password Protected Email Add In

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, .net-framework, c#

I am facing an issue.

I want my Microsoft Outlook email's to be password protected. I Google'd for it, came to know about "AddIn's for Outlook 2007" project.

Any tutorial on how to setup a password protected add-in to outlook 2007 ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a login for the program itself, but you can password protect your data file to keep others from viewing your stuff. Below is a link to how to set that up without using an add in.

[Set a password to help protect your Outlook information.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/set-a-password-to-help-protect-your-outlook-information-HA010149561.aspx)

*Note: this will not work in Exchange mode.*